# Can I use the "Serializer"?

Tags: android, parsing, xml-serialization, persistence

I have been looking around *teh internetz* for a quick and simple way to parse custom XML files which hold data elements and attributes as simple as this:

```
<book>
    <book type="sci-fi">
    <book cost="25">
</book>
```

And add to that I'll have a book class with these elements inside it.
And simple as that I could create an XML: file reading a book class and convert it to XML.
And also able to read an XML and convert into a new book class.

So I found this [thing](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#start)

Which includes these lines:

```
Serializer serializer = new Persister();
Example example = new Example("Example message", 123);
File result = new File("example.xml");

serializer.write(example, result);
```

Can I use these functions in Android apps? The Serializer and persister? Or is it called some how different?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to save one object into a local file.

Yes, in android you can use ObjectOutputStream class to write Object(writeObject method), and use ObjectOutputStream to save into a file. The corresponding read function class is ObjectInputStream. But,the foremost thing is that your class object to save must implement Serializable interface

Comment: Just mentioning it: Using Serializable assumes the contents of the class is already saved locally. If you are to retrieve some data from a server(say a book) you can't use Serializable. You would have to download the file and parse it. For storing these classes on a device though, using Serializable is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an XML parser that comes with Android. [Reference](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html#parse)

```
public List parse(InputStream in) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    try {
        XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
        parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
        parser.setInput(in, null);
        parser.nextTag();
        return readFeed(parser);
    } finally {
        in.close();
    }
}
```

This returns the parser, and returns the data. InputStream is the stream you read from.

Further, this is a copied example from the android documentation, with added explanations:

```
private List readFeed(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    List entries = new ArrayList();

    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "feed");//We read the parser inputted, but we try to find a specific tag. This can be the base tag, or if you have multiple of the same type, get the first.
    while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {//As long as the parser doesn't detect an end tag
        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {//and it isn't a start tag
            continue;
        }
        String name = parser.getName();//we parse the tag found by the reader
        //Then there are if-statements to determine what type of tag it is. This example uses a specific type to look for, as this looks for <entry>
        if (name.equals("entry")) {
            entries.add(readEntry(parser));//If it is that tag, add it to the list of content
        } else {
            skip(parser);//else skip it
        }
    }
    return entries;
}
```

Further, this can be applied to creating classes:

First, the entry class

```
public static class Entry {
    public final String title;
    public final String link;
    public final String summary;

    private Entry(String title, String summary, String link) {
        this.title = title;
        this.summary = summary;
        this.link = link;
    }
}
```

Then the parsing:

```
// Parses the contents of an entry. If it encounters a title, summary, or link tag, hands them off
// to their respective "read" methods for processing. Otherwise, skips the tag.
private Entry readEntry(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "entry");//finds the children of the tag "entry"
    String title = null;
    String summary = null;
    String link = null;
    while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            continue;
        }
        //and using if-statements, we find the different types of tags, and distribute the content to the appropriate strings
        String name = parser.getName();
        if (name.equals("title")) {
            title = readTitle(parser);
        } else if (name.equals("summary")) {
            summary = readSummary(parser);
        } else if (name.equals("link")) {
            link = readLink(parser);
        } else {
            skip(parser);
        }
    }
    //And finally, we create a new entry
    return new Entry(title, summary, link);
}

//The following methods are the methods used to parse the different tags. 
//They are used as separate methods to make it more clear what goes where, 
//instead of pushing all these into the same method
// Processes title tags in the feed.
private String readTitle(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "title");
    String title = readText(parser);
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "title");
    return title;
}

// Processes link tags in the feed.
private String readLink(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    String link = "";
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "link");
    String tag = parser.getName();
    String relType = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "rel");
    if (tag.equals("link")) {
        if (relType.equals("alternate")){
            link = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "href");
            parser.nextTag();
        }
    }
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "link");
    return link;
}

// Processes summary tags in the feed.
private String readSummary(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "summary");
    String summary = readText(parser);
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "summary");
    return summary;
}

// For the tags title and summary, extracts their text values.
private String readText(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    String result = "";
    if (parser.next() == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
        result = parser.getText();
        parser.nextTag();
    }
    return result;
}
  ...
}
```

And this can be modified rather easily to fit your needs: change the tag names to your tags, and modify the example class to whatever you want. I am not sure if you can get the price for an instance from attributes, but if you add sub-tags, you may get the same result. Example:

```
<book>
    <type>sci-fi</type>
    <cost>
        <currency>USD</currency>
        <price>25</price>
    </cost>
</book>
```

With cost you can also apply 25 directly.

Or you can continue to use the attribute system, but you will need to add some [more code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12389015/6296561). And further, the current XML file you have never closes the tags(`<book type="sci-fi">`), and you should not repeat the book-tag inside a book tag. Not because it is discouraged, but because you end up with a hard situation trying to find out what book tag the parser has found.

---

Further, to write an XML file, there are many different ways. For saving it locally, you can do it much more easily by using Serializable:

```
public class Something implements Serializable{
...
}
```

And then use Object[In/Out]putStream to read or write:

```
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("o.ser")));

    //Save the object
    oos.writeObject(instance);
    // close the writing.
    oos.close();
```

And to load:

```
ObjectInputStream ois= new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("o.ser")));

instance = (Something) ois.readObject();//or Something instance = (Something)...
ois.close;
```

But if you really want to save to a .xml file, here is one way:

(this uses internal storage, so this will be removed when the app is. The concept for external writing(public access areas) is the same, but a different writing method)

```
public static String getString(String basetag, List<String> tags/*Raw name, e.g. book*/, List<String> value){
    if(basetag == null || basetag.equals("") || basetag.equals(" ")){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("There has to be a base tag.");
    }
    String retval = "<" + basetag + ">\n";
    if(tags == null || value == null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("There have to be tags and values!");
    }
    if(tags.size() != value.size()){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("There has to be as many tags as there are values");
    }
    assert tags.size() != 0;
    assert value.size() != 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < tags.size(); i++){
        String s = "<%s>%s</%s>\n";
        retval += String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, s, tags.get(i), value.get(i), tags.get(i));
    }
    return retval;
}

public static void save(String filename, String data, Context c){

    if(data != null && filename != null) {
        try {
            //Create the file if not exists
            File file = new File(c.getFilesDir() + "/", filename);
            if (file.getParentFile().mkdirs())
                file.createNewFile();
            //Access file and write
            FileOutputStream fos = c.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos.write(data.getBytes());

            fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }else{
        throw new NullPointerException("Filename and/or data is null");
    }
}

private static List load(String fn, Context c){
    String collected = null;
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try{

        fis = c.openFileInput(fn);
        return parse(fis);

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }finally{
        try {
            fis.close();
        } catch(NullPointerException npe){
            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public static List parse(InputStream in) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    try {
        XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
        parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
        parser.setInput(in, null);
        parser.nextTag();
        return readFeed(parser);
    } finally {
        in.close();
    }
}
```

---

To end of this post, I really suggest you read [the android documentation on this subject](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html#parse) as it contains a lot of valuable information that may be more up to date than this answer(if it is a long time since the answer has been updated)